# Как указать на любой объект класса

Tags: ios, objective-c, делегаты

Я новичок в iOS разработке. Допустим есть класс Class1 и его делегат ClassD. Создаем обьекты классов class1 и сlassD и сообщаем что один делегат другого

```
сlass1.delegate = сlassD;
class2.delegate = сlassD;
class3.delegate = сlassD;
```

а так же создаем массив

```
NSArray* array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: class1, class2, class3, nil];
```

А есть ли способ упростить запись следующим способом

```
/*Любой обьект класса Class1*/.delegate = сlassD;

 NSArray* array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: /*Любой обьект класса Class1*/, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (id object in array)
   object.delegate = classD;
```